# _TypeError (type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map') flutter

Tags: mobile, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I did a similar post here : [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57977863/typeerror-type-listdynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-mapstring-dynamic) but i did the same and i have always the problem...

I have my class :

```
class PollQuestionsDto {
  int id;
  String entitled;
  int difficulty;
  List<Answer> answers;

  PollQuestionsDto({this.id, this.entitled, this.difficulty, this.answers});

  PollQuestionsDto.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    entitled = json['entitled'];
    difficulty = json['difficulty'];
    if (json['answers'] != null) {
      answers = new List<Answer>();
      json['answers'].forEach((v) {
        answers.add(new Answer.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['entitled'] = this.entitled;
    data['difficulty'] = this.difficulty;
    if (this.answers != null) {
      data['answers'] = this.answers.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}
```

Method for ask API :

```
Future<List<PollQuestionsDto>> getPollQuestions() async {
    String url = 'http://10.0.2.2:3000/v1/api/poll/40/question?page=0';
    //String url = 'http://10.0.2.2:3000/v1/api/poll/$idPoll/question?page=0';
    String token = await Candidate().getToken();
    final response = await http.get(url, headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    });
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(jsonDecode(response.body));
      /*List pollsList = jsonDecode(response.body) ;
      List<PollQuestionsDto> polls = [];
      for (var themeMap in pollsList) {
        polls.add(PollQuestionsDto.fromJson(themeMap));
      }
      print(polls);
      print('Get Poll ${response.body}');*/
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed get poll questions');
    }
  }
```

when i ask my API, the result of request is :

> {results: [{id: 2, entitled: Le langage utilisé sous Flutter est le dart ?, difficulty: 1, answers: [{id: 9, entitled: Oui, isCorrect: true}, {id: 10, entitled: Non, isCorrect: false}]}], pageCount: 3, next: http://localhost:3000/v1/api/poll/40/question?page=1, previous: }

When i want make the result in the list i have the same error :

> _TypeError (type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map')

Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the result is

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "entitled": "Le langage utilisé sous Flutter est le dart ?",
      "difficulty": 1,
      "answers": [
        {
          "id": 9,
          "entitled": "Oui",
          "isCorrect": true
        },
        {
          "id": 10,
          "entitled": "Non",
          "isCorrect": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "pageCount": 3,
  "next": "http://localhost:3000/v1/api/poll/40/question?page=1"
}
```

you need to add `['results']` like this:

```
List pollsList = jsonDecode(jsonstr)['results'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast `json['answers']` to `List` like

```
    if (json['answers'] != null) {
      answers = (json['answers'] as List).map((v) => Answer.fromJson(v)).toList();
    }
```

Its better to use `https://pub.dev/packages/json_annotation` instead of implementing `toJson` and `fromJson` by hand unless you have special requirement.

I am able to parse following string

```
    [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "entitled": "yes",
        "difficulty": 1,
        "answers": [
          {
            "value":"a"
          }
        ]        
      }
    ]
```

using

```
class PollQuestionsDto {
  int id;
  String entitled;
  int difficulty;
  List<Answer> answers;

  PollQuestionsDto({this.id, this.entitled, this.difficulty, this.answers});

  PollQuestionsDto.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    entitled = json['entitled'];
    difficulty = json['difficulty'];
    if (json['answers'] != null) {
      answers = new List<Answer>();
      json['answers'].forEach((v) {
        answers.add(new Answer.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['entitled'] = this.entitled;
    data['difficulty'] = this.difficulty;
    if (this.answers != null) {
      data['answers'] = this.answers.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }

  @override String toString() => toJson().toString();

  static List<PollQuestionsDto> arrayOfQuestionsFromJson(String json) {
    return (jsonDecode(json) as List).map((e) => PollQuestionsDto.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }
}
```

Is this what you are expecting (Your might have to change json for Answer as I used Anser class with one variable `value`)??

Comment: Have you tried your solution by just replacing `json['answers']` with `json['answers'] as List`?

Comment: I did this :   Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['entitled'] = this.entitled;
    data['difficulty'] = this.difficulty;
    if (data['answers'] != null) {
      answers = (data['answers'] as List).map((v) => Answer.fromJson(v)).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }

Comment: And i have always the same error @Chenna Reddy _TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>')

Comment: @MayuriXx Updated answer with sample, check `arrayOfQuestionsFromJson`

Comment: i edited my post with your example but i have always my error...